# PHP Word Censor help, censor word based on a criteria using regex

Tags: php, regex

Hi all im trying to build a regular expression which will sustain the following criteria.

Word to be censored in this example "view".
Character to be used after censor: "%", since "*" mess up my post formatting.

**Examples of word use:**
view
 
views
preview
I went to see the great view
The view was great wasn't it.

**Example after word censor:**
%%%%
views
preview
I went to see the great %%%%
The %%%% was great wasn't it.

Here is some code I have:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\s*'. preg_quote($word, '\\') .'\s*/is', 'bbcode_callback_censored', $string);
```

Trouble is this matches everything right now since i use "*" in the regex ater "\s". Any ideas what I could do to fulfill my criteria?

Comment: I'm not really shure what you want to do. If you just want to replace a word I'd use str_replace

Comment: I have provided examples inside the original post based on a word that i would like to censor "view". The first example shows all the possible uses of this word, then another example below shows what would happen if my regular expression was successful. Str_replace will not do this, as it isn't powerful enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't match for whitespace, use a **[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**

Try

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\b'. preg_quote($word, '\\') .'\b/is', 'bbcode_callback_censored', $string);
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30vkd)

You just need to make sure that the content of `$word` does not start or end with a non word character, then the word boundary will not work.

`\b` is a word boundary. It matches on a change from a word character (as defined in `\w`) to a non word character as defined in `\W`, or the other way round.

**Alternative: *whitespace boundary***

If you don't like the word boundary because it is possible that your word to replace starts or end with non word characters like "#view", define your own "whitespace boundary", e.g. like this:

```
(?<=^|\s)#view(?=$|\s)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30vkm)

Would look in your code like this

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|\s)'. preg_quote($word, '\\') .'(?=$|\s)/is', 'bbcode_callback_censored', $string);
```

`(?<=^|\s)` will match if there is the Start of the String or whitespace before

`(?=$|\s)` will match if there is the end of the String or whitespace ahead

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth look at it. I'm experimenting with word boundary and it seems to be working great. I'd +1 this but I don't have enough rep yet. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ThomasSultana, you can't upvote yet, but you are able to accept the answer that helped you.

Comment: Done, just figured out how to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use slow and memory hungry regex engine for this simple task, use `str_replace` — it replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.

```
$string = str_replace(' view ','%',$string);
```

Comment: But this will also remove the view in "preview",

Comment: True, but it deals with the problem of words starting with non-word character. A workaround is to put spaces in quotes of search string.

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

```
$text_without_views = preg_replace('/(^|\W)view($|\W)/','\1***\2',$text_with_views);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "view viewing view view";
$str = preg_replace('/(^|\b)view(\b|$)/is', ' %%%% ', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: No need for the alternations. `\b` will also match on the start and the end of the string.